# defining empty list template in angular-ui-tree

Tags: angular-ui-tree

does anyone know if there's a way to define a template for an empty ui-tree list?

If the list model ist empty there will be a default

```
<div class="angular-ui-tree-empty"></div>
```

element generated (if not turned off by data-empty-placeholder-enabled), but I want to define some HTML for it by myself.

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Comment: Have you tired to check if tree is empty? then using `ng-if`, show your template for empty tree